# Uploading large files from the front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone, large-file-upload

I am trying to understand what is the best method in which large files can be uploaded to a server from the front-end. For the front-end, I make use of a library called [`react-dropzone`](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) which allows me to get information on file that I that I intend to upload. My upload component looks something like this:

```
// Node Modules
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export default function Upload() {
  // i18n
  const [t] = useTranslation();

  // React Dropzone
  const onDrop = useCallback((droppedFiles) => {
    console.log(droppedFiles);
  }, []);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop});

  return (
    <div className="upload" {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {isDragActive ? (
        <p>{t('DROP_FILES_HERE')}</p>
      ) : (
        <p>{t('DRAG_AND_DROP_FILES_HERE_OR_CLICK_TO_SELECT_FILES')}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This provides me access to the file's contents such as its name,type, and size in bytes.[image: Contents for example file upload]
This library seems to also work for files that are larger (100+ MB), but the question I have is how do I call upon this data when I want to upload this?

One thought I had was to use `localStorage` but the maximum size seems to be around [5 to 10 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values/42314583#42314583). I also use `Redux` within the front-end however, but I do not think that using its `store` would be ideal for large files.

This brings me an [article](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/) I read which stored the file within in React state, however this example seems to use files that are smaller in size such as photos. **My question is would using this approach work for larger files in the order of 100's of MB's?**

```
// Node Modules
import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

export default function Upload() {
  // i18n
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  // State
  const [files, setFiles] = useState();

  // React Dropzone
  const onDrop = useCallback((droppedFiles) => {
    setFiles(droppedFiles);
  }, []);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop});

  return (
    <div className="upload" {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {isDragActive ? (
        <p>{t('DROP_FILES_HERE')}</p>
      ) : (
        <p>{t('DRAG_AND_DROP_FILES_HERE_OR_CLICK_TO_SELECT_FILES')}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I plan on chunking the file into smaller portions when uploading to the server with [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) but I am unfamiliar on the size limitation of React state, so is this the best approach for uploading larger files?

Comment: You can just upload a large file in the same way you would upload a small file. There is no React state limitation here. Chunking the file is unnecessary, most modern browsers/backend servers handle file transfer much more efficiently than you would with chunking.

Comment: Is this resolved?